# Multiple iterations of k means in python

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis

I have an dataset X of size (n_samples, 2). They form 3 clusters fairly consistently with k-means (k=3), I'd like to run 3-means 10,000 times to validate the consistency of clustering patterns. By doing this, I get a dataframe like:

```
sample_name | iter1 | iter2 | iter3 | ...
------------|-------|-------|-------|
x1          | 1     | 0     | 1     |
x2          | 1     | 0     | 1     |
x3          | 1     | 0     | 2     |
x4          | 0     | 1     | 2     |
x5          | 0     | 1     | 2     |
x6          | 0     | 1     | 2     |
x7          | 2     | 2     | 0     |
x8          | 2     | 2     | 0     |
x9          | 2     | 2     | 0     |
```

...and so on, up to 10,000 iterations (columns), where '0', '1' and '2' are the cluster labels assigned by k-means. As in the example, the data clusters very well, but the (arbitrary) names given to these clusters changes at every run. How can I standardize the naming to something like:

```
sample_name | iter1 | iter2 | iter3 | ...
------------|-------|-------|-------|
x1          | a     | a     | a     |
x2          | a     | a     | a     |
x3          | a     | a     | b     |
x4          | b     | b     | b     |
x5          | b     | b     | b     |
x6          | b     | b     | b     |
x7          | c     | c     | c     |
x8          | c     | c     | c     |
x9          | c     | c     | c     |
```

So that I can eventually get the majority vote of cluster membership of each x_i by iterating down the rows?

Comment: I highly doubt there's anything you can do, the clusters might be the same but they may be labelled in any order. And no, that isn't really something you can change.

Comment: There are probably a lot of advanced techniques possible (assuming a formalized task). Why not the following: get the centroids after each kmeans; order them (in your case of 2d; e.g. from lower-left to upper-right): label according to this order.

Answer (score 1):

You need to relabel the clusters, for example on a max overlap.

There are different strategies. You could greedily try to match by the maximum overlap, or you could use the Hungarian algorithm. But with just 3 clusters, you can do a brute force approach, and **just test all 6 possible permutations** for the one with the best match.

Because of this problem, most evaluation measures ignore the actual labels. They work on pairs of points instead.